# What's the kube-public namespace for?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

Just curious about the intent for this default namespace.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That namespace exists in clusters created with kubeadm for now. It contains a single ConfigMap object, cluster-info, that aids discovery and security bootstrap (basically, contains the CA for the cluster and such). This object is readable without authentication.

If you are courious:

```
$ kubectl get configmap -n kube-public cluster-info -o yaml
```

There are more details in this [blog post](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/stronger-foundation-for-creating-and-managing-kubernetes-clusters/) and the [design document](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/cluster-lifecycle/bootstrap-discovery.md#new-kube-public-namespace):

> ### NEW: kube-public namespace
>
> [...] To create a config map that everyone can see, we introduce a new kube-public namespace. This namespace, by convention, is readable by all users (including those not authenticated). [...]
>
> In the initial implementation the kube-public namespace (and the cluster-info config map) will be created by kubeadm. That means that these won't exist for clusters that aren't bootstrapped with kubeadm. [...]

Answer (score -1):

To complete the previous answer, these are the objects inside the namespace `kube-public`:

```
$ kubectl get_all --namespace kube-public
NAME                                                                      NAMESPACE
secret/default-token-jd2k2                                                kube-public
serviceaccount/default                                                    kube-public
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:bootstrap-signer  kube-public
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:bootstrap-signer         kube-public
```

Comment: could you share your get_all alias or do you have a custom kubectl?

Comment: Install the krew plugin manager for kubectl and search for the `get_all` plugin